# SQL文の実行結果をif文の条件判定に利用して[object]が返ってきたときに後続のスクリプトが動作しない

Tags: javascript, sql-server

## 動作環境

ブラウザ：IE8
sqlserver：Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008

## やりたいこと

ASPXファイルから下記のJavascript関数を呼び出して処理しています。
sqlServerに対するSELECT結果がテーブルに存在しない[object]だったときに、if文のelse処理が動作するはずですが、else以降の処理が動作せず、関数呼び出しが終了してしまいます。

SELECT結果の[object]を条件分岐で正常に判断させる方法を知りたいです。
もしくはSELECT結果の使用方法が間違っていたり、他の方法で判断する方法があるのであれば正しい使用方法、その手段も知りたいです。

```js
function checkSMT_Z120(regClass, obj, z120, ovday, odlvprice) {
    //エラー回避　※try{～
    try {
        var objADO = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");     //ADODBモジュールを使用してDBへ接続
        var inputchk = obj.value                                //入力された品番を引数として取得
        var companyGrp = z120.value                             //入力されたz120グループを引数として取得
        var formVday = frmFormData.elements[ovday];             //旧有効開始日をフォームに返す
        var formoDlvPrice = frmFormData.elements[odlvprice];    //旧納品価格をフォームに返す
        var formregClass = frmFormData.elements[regClass];      //登録区分をフォームに返す

        //1.ADOを使いSQL ServerのDBを開きます
        objADO.Open("Driver={SQL Server};" +
                    "server=[ip]; database=[db名]; uid=[****]; pwd=[****];");

        //2.SQLを実行して対象テーブルの登録状況を参照
        if (inputchk != "") {
            var ret = objADO.Execute("select 品番,金額,数量,開始日付 from Z120 where 得意先G5 = '" + companyGrp
                                                                                                 + "' and 品番 = '" + inputchk
                                                                                                 + "' and 終了日付 = '99991231'");
            if (ret("品番") != "[object]") {
                window.alert("true")
            } else {
                window.alert("false")
            }
        }
        
        //ADOをクローズします
        objADO.Close();
        objADO = null;

    }
    catch (e) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらく処理に必要な値は`ret("品番")`ではなく`ret("品番").Value`なのではないでしょうか。

`ret("品番")`は`ADODB.Field`型です。この型は文字列に変換すると`[object]`となりますが、文字列`"[object]"`と比較しても一致することはありません。

Answer (score 0):

Connection オブジェクトの Execute の実行結果は Recordset オブジェクトが返ります。
エラー出ない限りオブジェクトが返されるので、[object]しか返らないと思います。
レコードが正常に取得できたかどうかについては、自分が HTA などで作る場合は Recordset オブジェクトの EOF プロパティで判定します。ブール型で返すので、if (ret.EOF) {} みたいな使い方でいけるはずです。

[Connection.Execute メソッド - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc364125.aspx)

先頭の1行だけを取得するならこのコードで良いですが、複数行処理する場合は MoveNext, EOF などを使ってループ処理にします。